# How to connect to DB in private network from local system

Tags: networking, proxy, portforwarding

Currently I have a docker image running Alpine Linux inside a private network. I have root access to that docker image.

On the same private network, there is a database instance. Only systems on the same network can access the database ( Ex: The aforementioned docker image )

Right now, to debug things inside the DB, I had to SSH to the docker image then run command line tools from inside that docker image. That is quite complicated

Is there a way for me to connect to that Database, using development tools inside my local PC, instead? I am not sure if the term for this is port-forward or proxying

Note: I do **not** have SSH access to the host of Docker container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do what I wanted:

- If we have normal SSH connection, https://superuser.com/questions/1633408/how-to-connect-to-db-on-private-network-from-local-machine
- If no normal SSH connection can be made (Kubernete pod) install HAProxy on the container/pod and set-up [port-forward](https://gist.github.com/cmer/e58e90dbf820a850ff4f136f85697be0)